# Raspberry Pi 4 64-bit with RTC (Hardware Clock DS3231) Daylight Saving Time without Internet?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, rtc

I am using a hardware clock to set the time on my RPI4. It does not use the internet.
The timezone on the PI is set to Europe/Berlin. The HW Clock runs on UTC.
So when day light saving time occurs, Europe/Berlin will be UTC+1 instead of UTC+2 in autumn.
Will my RPI show the correct time or will it be stuck at UTC+2, since it doesn't have internet to know when it changes?

Thanks!

Comment: DS3231 is very powerful and can do (almost) anything you wish. There are cheap modules in AliExpress, and tutorials from AdaFruit, SparkFun, or WaveShare. Usually their libraries are not very comprehensive, so if you are OK with python, you can DIY your own functions. You might like to read my old posts (altogether over 50!) from rpi.org.forum on how I learn from the very beginning, finally to a fully debugged, workable, and easy to expand python program: DS3232 Basic Test Using Python
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1346190&hilit=DS3231+tlfong01#p1346190.

Comment: The RTC should be set to UTC (CEST -2, CET -1) all year round. The timezone stuff will then set the local clock to Europe/Berlin. Don't set the hwclock to local - it just causes problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DST time setting on *Raspberry Pi OS* (like most Linux systems) has NOTHING to do with the RTC (or any other time source) which should be set to UTC.

On *Raspberry Pi OS* it is controlled by Localisation Settings - most conveniently configured by `raspi-config`.

Comment: Thanks, so Raspberry Pi Localization set to Europe/Berlin will automatically take care of the DST whenever it occurs, even without Internet? My RTC is set to UTC.

Comment: Linux has a database of timezone information. It needs a connection to the Internet in order to update that database (when the rules change). It doesn't need a connection in order to apply those rules. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98137/how-exactly-is-tzdata-database-used for more information.

Comment: @zer02 the timezone rules can change and to ensure these are correct the OS must be updated. Most DST changes now occur on internationally agreed dates which are aligned across northern and southern hemispheres (USA and tropics excluded). DST rule changes (at least for Europe and similar stable administrations) are infrequent  and usually have long leadtimes.